# add data on sql using javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

Hello i want to add data on database in sql but i can't find how to do this using javascript,i work on visual studio

Comment: Do you know how to add data using sql?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any other resources or examples? Are you using VS just for Javascript, or do you also have ASP, MVC, WebApi or any other such toolkit/framework? More info is needed if any help is to be found.

Comment: This requires some work both server and client-side. Google breeze.js for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to pass data back to your .NET MVC C# Controller method

```
var myViewModel = {};

  var team= {};
  team.TeamID = 1234;
  team.TeamName = "Test Team";

  myViewModel.Team= team;

  var teamPlayerList = [];

  var player1= {};
  player1.id= "1";
  player1.Name = "Patrick";

  var player2 = {};
  player2.id= "2";
  player2.Name = "Padraig";

  teamPlayerList.push(player1);
  teamPlayerList.push(player2 );

  myViewModel.TeamPlayerList = teamPlayerList;

  $.ajax(
  {
   url: 'Team/Create',
   data: JSON.stringify({teamViewModel : myViewModel}),
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (data) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function () { alert('error'); }
});
```

On the backend in the C# you will need A controller class, and some C# classes to hold the data you pass in from javascript

```
public class Team
{
 public long TeamID { get; set; }
 public string TeamName { get; set; }
}

public class TeamPlayer
{
 public string id{ get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A ViewModel

```
public class TeamViewModel
{
 public Team Team { get; set; }
 public IList<TeamPlayer> TeamPlayerList { get; set; }
}
```

The controllers method will be something like this

```
  public class TeamController : Controller
  {
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(TeamViewModel teamViewModel)
   {
   //USE HERE TO EXTRACT DATA PASSED IN

     var myTeam = teamViewModel.Team;
     var teamPlayerList = teamViewModel.TeamPlayerList;

     //call your db insert class/code and use values passed in
   return Content("success");
  }
```